# Create Android App 'about' page integrating Google Map

Tags: android, dictionary

what is the best method to create an app about page, to show a location through which users can just link themselves to the maps application for navigation.
Thank you,

Comment: If it is allways the same location, just use an image

Comment: Thats right, but i want the user to be able to navigate to the location using a button. how may i do that?

Comment: Set an OnClickListener on the ImageView that starts an intent to launch the Maps app.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Intent with a ["geo:" uri](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) and call startActivity() with it.